# iOS8/Swift and MobileVLCKit build fails

Tags: swift, ios8, vlc

I'm struggling a bit to build my project with MobileVLCKit and cocoapods.
Without adding any VLCKit code, I get errors when building the app, on simulator or device.

Pod file:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'VLCKitTest' do
  pod 'MobileVLCKit'
end
```

This is the error I get

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::string const&)", referenced from:
      libebml::CRTError::CRTError(std::string const&, int) in MobileVLCKit(StdIOCallback.o)
  "std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<void const*>(void const*)", referenced from:
      libebml::IOCallback::writeFully(void const*, unsigned long) in MobileVLCKit(IOCallback.o)
      libebml::IOCallback::readFully(void*, unsigned long) in MobileVLCKit(IOCallback.o)

      [...]
```

My deployment target is 8.0.
I have set my "Build Active Architecture Only" to YES in Debug.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally succeeded to compile my project using a specially iOS8 compiled version of the library by Felix Paul Kühne, Lead Developer of VLC for OS X and iOS.

Check out the link near the end of the discussion:

https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=128011&p=430329#p430329

Comment: too sad, the file isn't available anymore and no comments left on how to compile this "special" build

Answer (score 7):

In addition to doing what *Mukesh Thawani* said;

> *Change C++ Standard Library to libstdc++ in the Build Settings.*

I also needed to add the **libstdc++.6.tbd** binary in **Build Phases** -> **Link Binary With Libraries**.

This worked for me with **iOS 9.0**.

Answer (score 2):

Change C++ Standard Library to libstdc++ in the Build Settings.

Comment: I still get the same error after changing the setting unfortunately

Comment: Clean the code and restart the app. Sometimes this solves the problem.

Comment: I still have the same issue. I tried to add the lib in "Link Binary with Libraries" but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: so your project builds right after integrating MobileVLCKit with cocoapods?

Comment: After searching a bit I succeeded in compiling an objective C project with a 6.1 deployment target, unfortunately I need to make it work on iOS8 with swift

Comment: See this error not only comes with MobileVLCKit but comes with other frameworks too, so mine was with different frameworks, but that is solved after updating the library.